# Project in Python3, reading files, word data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given data to read that has a word, then is entered down and has two numbers separated by a comma. for example "airport" is on one line and then the next line is "2007,175702". I have the following code at this point.

```
def readFile(file):
    d= {}
    for line in open(file):
       x = line.strip()
       text = x.split(',')
       if len(text) == 1:
          word = text[0]
       else:
          lst = createYearCount(int(text[0]), int(text[1]))
          if line not in d:
              d[word] = [lst]
           else:
               d[word].append(lst)
    print(d)


My current output is this: {'request': [YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )], 'wandered': [YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], 'airport': [YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )]}
```

When it should have the output of all YearCount objects for each word. So for airport it should have

```
[YearCount( year=2007, count=175702), YearCount(year=2008, count=173294)]
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data from your file? Like a 5 or more lines of it.

Comment: The output has been fixed but thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You wrote `if line not in d:` but i think you wanted to be `if word not in d:`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10317135)

Comment: Thanks for input, haywire, but there's no question. He showed the output and he said what should be the output. He will get the desired output if he corrects the mistake. I believe it's a mistake because the code as it is will never reach the "d[word].append(lst)" line.

Comment: Yes, maybe this should be a comment not an answer, but the question is 7 hours old without an answer and I don't have the permission to comment on it. Soon :}.